# to detect column content in new row in ag-grid for angular2

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-react

I am trying to add a new row dynamically when user selects 'NEW' in ag-grid. It has only one column. And I tried so hard to capture the value in the column without selecting any other column  or press 'ENTER'. But most of the methods in ag-grid would detect the changes only some event fires.

[I have to use (keyup) method to detect the text entered but it doesn't detect the][1] column dynamically. I tried `(cellClicked)`, `(cellChanged)` or `getSelectedNodes()` etc. I also tried 'checkBoxSelection'.But not able to capture the column value.

Appreciate your help on this. Attached the link for the image. Inserted the code. I can capture the userentered value in the column when he selects ADD but not able to capture with out going to other tab or press 'ENTER'.

```html
 private onCellValueChanged($event) {
        console.log('onCellValueChanged');
        const updateData: Object = {
            _id : $event.data._id,
            AN_workingGroups: $event.data.AN_workingGroups
        }
        console.log(updateData);        

        this.service.updateAnnexData(this.workingGroups, updateData).then((data) => {
           console.log(data)       
        });

        console.log('onCellValueChanged: ' + $event.oldValue + ' to ' + $event.newValue);
    }
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MfIi.png`enter code here`

Comment: I don't understand what "capture the value in the column" refers to. Where does the user enter the text? Try adding some screenshots showing the process you're going through, or a demo.

Comment: welcome to [so], would you mind sharing your code on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you? also go through how to create [mcve]

Comment: Thanks guys, posted the image and the code where I am capturing (cellValueChanged), but I want to capture the $event.target.value without going to other tab or selecting 'ENTER" after user entered the value